# JSONPath expression works with Data flow simulator but not with step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to use the InputPath filter in AWS Step Functions to select a portion of the JSON state input to use with a JSONPath expression.

**Data**

```
[
  {
    "ticker": "DE30_EUR",
    "granularity": "M"
  },
  {
    "ticker": "DE30_EUR",
    "granularity": "W"
  },
  {
    "ticker": "DE30_EUR",
    "granularity": "D"
  },
  {
    "ticker": "DE30_EUR",
    "granularity": "H1"
  }
]
```

**Current JSONPath expression**

```
$[?(@.granularity==H1),?(@.granularity==D),?(@.granularity==W)]
```

This works when using the AWS Step Functions Data flow simulator with the data above and only returns array items with granularity of "H1", "D" or "W".

**Issue**

However, when using this with step functions as the InputPath or OutputPath it returns an empty array which is not the same as the  Data flow simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below **JSONPath**

```
$[?(@.granularity=='H1'|| @.granularity=='D' || @.granularity=='W')]
```

Comment: This is what I originally tried with the AWS data flow simulator and it fails with error `No results for path: '$[?(@.granularity=='H1'|| @.granularity=='D' || @.granularity=='W')]' in state input JSON.` but I tried it again now with step functions and you are right it does work.  Seems the data flow simulator syntax  is not aligned with step functions syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The following is quoted from the aws documentation, This limitation is very incomprehensible to me.

> A reference path is a path whose syntax is limited in such a way that it can identify only a single node in a JSON structure:
>
> - You can access object fields using only dot (.) and square bracket ([ ]) notation.
> - The operators @ .. , : ? * aren't supported.
> - Functions such as length() aren't supported.

Reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-paths.html